# How to know if an object was created by Immutable

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I need to detect if an object is some kind of Immutable or not.  How do I do this?

Comment: Lots of good info in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907470/how-to-check-if-object-is-immutable

Note that `isIterable` returns false for the `Record` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Iterable.isIterable`

```
Immutable.Iterable.isIterable(Immutable.Map()); // true
Immutable.Iterable.isIterable({}); // false
```

http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Iterable/isIterable

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/450

Doesn't look like they've gotten around to making a cleaner API for this, but for now you can use `Immutable.Iterable.isIterable()` to check if something is an iterable immutable collection.