# How can I find the 'typeof' immutable.js data structure being used?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

In JS, you can find the typeof a JS primitive by console logging it with the 'typeof' keyword. Is there an equivalent keyword for immutable.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if object is Immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907470/how-to-check-if-object-is-immutable)

Comment: A pojo is only one type of JS primitive. This is not to test whether any of the primitives have been converted to an immutable; but rather what type of immutable it have been converted to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Immutable.Iterable.isIterable().

Please check this reference https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/450

**An additional information :-** 
Using ‘instanceof’ is a misleading function which leads developers to think in a wrong way, but it is not recommended because when you require different copies of Immutable.js then it may return False